# ¿Cómo ocultar un botón completamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

En una aplicación que estoy haciendo necesito que unos botones se oculten completamente(no como el `state="disable"` que deshabilita el botón pero lo deja visible).

¿Hay algún comando o algo para hacer eso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalmente esto implica remover el widget de la ventana (sin destruirlo). Depende del método (geometry manager) que uses para posicionar el widget en la ventana/padre:

```
btn.place() --> btn.place_forget()
btn.grid()  --> btn.grid_forget()
btn.pack()  --> btn.pack_forget()
```

En el caso de `grid` o `pack` los demás widgets se reacomodan para ocupar el espacio dejado libre. Para volver a mostrar el widget hay que volver a llamar al `pack`/`place`/`grid` de nuevo.

Si estamos usando `grid` suele ser preferible usar `grid_remove`, ya que a la hora de volver a mostrar el widget, la configuración original es recordada por lo que basta con hacer `btn.grid()`, sin tener que especificar de nuevo fila, columna, etc.

Un ejemplo con `place` que demuestra como ocultar y volver a mostrar un botón:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry('200x200')


def btn_hide():
    if b1.winfo_ismapped():
        b1.place_forget()
        b2.configure(text="Mostrar Botón 1")
    else:
        b1.place(x=70, y=50)
        b2.configure(text="Ocultar Botón 1")


b1 = tk.Button(ventana, text="Botón 1", fg="black", width=5)
b1.place(x=70, y=50)
b2 = tk.Button(ventana, text="Ocultar Botón 1", command=btn_hide, fg="black", width=10)
b2.place(x=50, y=90)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aplica para label?